# Using .htaccess to rewrite my url with _GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to rewrite my url currently www.example.com/storepage.php?name={ANYNUMBER}

I want to make the URL look like this, www.example.com/store/{ANY NUMBER}

I have created a .htaccessfile and have come up with this code, is it written wrong for what i want to achieve ?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^storepage/([0-999]+)/?$    storepage.php?name=$1
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you tell us more about the error you are facing, *"wrong for what i want to achieve"*?

Comment: @Manikiran Strangely enough it does nothing, the URL is unchanged,

Comment: What url are you entering? as the code you have will not cause a redirect from `www.example.com/storepage.php?name={ANYNUMBER}` to `www.example.com/store/{ANY NUMBER}`

it will only cause if you enter `www.example.com/store/{ANY NUMBER}` to work like you actually visited `www.example.com/storepage.php?name={ANYNUMBER}`

Comment: it does not change your url's you have to do that.

Comment: Here is my URL : ukvoucherhub.co.uk

Comment: if you have any suggestions to what to change in the .htaccess i can upload through FTP and you can view them live, if you done mind helping

Comment: @DavidJones Yes i would just like the URL to look more presentable,

Comment: maybe something like this

`Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^storepage.php?name=(.*)$ /storepage/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^storepage/([0-9]+)/?$ /storepage.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
`

Comment: @DavidJones Strangely enough the URL is unchanged and shows in browser as it did before

Comment: Franky i find "pretty links" a waist of time